# SwiftUI: get collection with array of object - Cloud firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, nested-object

How can I fetch data of collection that contain an array of objects?

I don't have any error the data are returned in logs correctly but they don't store in the list var that I created

My struct ->

```
struct Question: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var answers: [Answer]?
    var text: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case answers
        case text
    }
}

struct Answer: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String? 
    var text: String?
    var isCorrect: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case isCorrect
        case text
    }
}
```

My attempt so far, from which I get nothing in return:

```
    func fetchData() {
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Questions").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in

            if let err = error {
                 print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
             } else {

                 // Update the list property in the main thread
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.list = querySnapshot!.documents.map { d in

                         return Question(id: d.documentID,
                                         answers: d["answers"] as? [Answer],
                                         type: d["type"] as? String,
                                         text: d["text"] as? String)

                     }
                 }
                 print("==================")
                 for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                     print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                 }
                 print("==================")
             }//else
        }
    }
```

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRkUb.png)

Comment: Can you show your attempt so far? The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) has pretty good examples that you can start with.

Comment: '    func fetchData() {
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Questions").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }

            self.list = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Question? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Question.self)
            }
        }
    }'

I get nothing in return

Comment: Use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` inside the `catch` and I bet you'll see an error message that gives you a useful hint.